# how to generate a fixed width file from snowflake and unload to internal stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to generate a fixed width file from snowflake tables and unload it into internal stage.

Could you please guide me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exact requirement as in what is implied by "fixed-width file"? Adding a sample or some screenshot for illustrating it would be good.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have multiple snowflake tables(reference tables) and using these tables, i need to identify required columns and generate a fixed width file with specified size by concatenating all the columns in a simple text file format and unload into snowflake internal stage.

Comment: Have you tried using a view that concatenates the columns together with an `RPAD` function to add spaces where needed?

Comment: I haven't tried yet but before that, just thought of checking that, does snowflake support loading/unloading fixed width file? any idea? if yes, could you please share some examples. Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, you'd need to create a single-column view and export that as a delimited file, so using a view with concatenate and `RPAD` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to simple concatenate the columns and then add sufficient white space create the width required.

For example if we wanted a column with fixed width of 100, we could do:

```sql
USE ROLE SYSADMIN;
USE "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1";
SELECT RPAD(CONCAT(R_NAME, R_COMMENT), 100) FROM REGION;
```