# Snowflake output from a view needs to be in a specific TXT format rather than a CSV or TSV

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In order to send a file to a vendor, I need to write the output from a view (or a query) in snowflake to a TXT file in a specific format like the one below (currently in SAS). I have tried exporting it a TSV file but does not work. The TXT file is too big to manually change anything on it. Has anyone tried this in the past and what are the workarounds for it?

```
 put  (ACCT_NUM)(10. -r) @12(ID) (z12. -r) (Amount) (9.2 -r)@33(First_Name) ($char32. -l)  @65(Last_Name) ($char32. -l)@97(First_Name_1) ($char32. -l) @129(Last_Name_1) ($char32. -l)  (Address_1) ($char38. -l)(Insert_spaces) ($char4. -l);
  putnames= no;
run;
```

Comment: I don't speak SAS, what is this "specific TXT format" that is being defined here? Is it fixed-width? Can you share a sample record or two and then share an example of the desired output?

Comment: `The TXT file is too big to manually change anything...` How big is the resulting file? If it's 16MB or smaller, I have an approach that will work. Let me know about the size first, and if it's under 16MB I'll write it up.

Comment: It is about 1MB only!

Comment: Did you see this similar question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643719/how-to-generate-a-fixed-width-file-from-snowflake-and-unload-to-internal-stage   Do you know what your SAS code does? Or do you need help understanding the SAS code?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to make a text file with the data in fixed positions.

If you cannot find a method in SNOWFLAKE to make such a file just build the line as a character variable and then write that one variable to the file.  It will not matter whether you tell it to use comma or tab as the delimiter since it will be writing only one variables.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what a character variable is. Can you please explain?

Comment: A value like 'FRED" is stored in a character variable. A value like 1234 is stored in  numeric variable.  Snowflake (or any SQL implementation) will have a way for you to convert numbers to character strrings and way to concatenate character strings together to make longer strings. I assume you know what the SAS code you posed means.  Your PUT statement is just using SAS formats to translate your variables into strings and write them.  Just convert them your self and paste them together to generate the same line of text for each observation.